# WPF mvvm routes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm in progress to create a desktop application in C# with WPF but i'm stuck with my menu.
I have a left panel menu to switch between functionality.

I created one viewmodel with 2 views which need to be display in my main window. if i'm clicking on Monitoring, the content view switch from Home to Monitoring but when i'm on Monitoring, If I try to back on Home, it's not working and I don't understand why.

**Below my project folder**

([abc] = Folder; - abc = file) :

```
[PROJECT]   
    [assets]
        - Home.png
        - Stats.png
    [ViewModels]
        - MainWindowViewModel.cs
    [Views]
        - Home.xaml
        - Home.cs
        - Stats.xaml
        - Stats.cs
    - MainWindow.xaml
    - MainWindow.cs
    - App.xaml
    - App.cs
    - App.config
```

Below important part of my code :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HomeViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <views:Home DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StatsViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <views:Stats DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="OpenHome">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="/assets/home.png" Height="32" Width="32" />
    <Label Content="Home" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,5,5,5" />
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="OpenStats">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="/assets/stats.png" Height="32" Width="32" />
    <Label Content="Monitoring" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,5,5,5" />
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HomeViewTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Route}" Value="Home">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HomeViewTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Route}" Value="Stats">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StatsViewTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
private MainWindowViewModel MV = new MainWindowViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void OpenHome(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MV.Route = "Home";
    DataContext = MV;
}

private void OpenStats(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MV.Route = "Stats";
    DataContext = MV;
}
```

**ViewModels>MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public string Route
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(){}
}
```

Comment: Do not use a DataTemplate to display single ViewModel object, try `Page` or `UserControl`. In addition, your question seem not clear enough, you can give some screenshot to illustrate

Comment: @Flithor, it is perfectly fine to use DataTemplate to display an object which is not Visual itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send notifications about changes for `Route` property via `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _Route;
    public string Route
    {
        get { return _Route; }
        set { _Route = value; OnPropertyChanged("Route"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(){}
}
```

Such notification will activate DataTrigger which in turn will change ContentTemplate

Comment: Ok I understand the way now.
Thank you, it's working right now. :)